# IMAP: Error: Permission deny missing +w perm?

Tags: postfix, mail, dovecot, imap

I'm trying to create a local mail server with postfix, apache2, dovecot and squirrelmail. but i'm got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lps73.jpg) error when I login squirrelmail in browser. Please help me.

Comment: I think you need to add yourself to the `mail group`: `sudo usermod -a -G mail thehai`, or using `sudo gpasswd -a thehai mail`

Comment: Yes as @George says. actually it says it in your output: "... we're not in group 8(mail), dir owned by 0:8"

Comment: Never post textual messages as images, they prevent copy-pasting and are not searchable. Have a look at the [FAQ] for formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf

```
mail_privileged_group = mail
```

And make sure this:

```
groupadd -g 5000 vmail
useradd -g vmail -u 5000 vmail -d /var/mail
chown -R vmail:vmail /var/mail
```